# NSString.length causes crash (NSInvalidArgumentException)

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, ios8.1

I have a iPad app (XCode 6.1.1, iOS 8.1, ARC) that when I run it on the 8.1 simulator, the app crashes comparing the length of a string.  This has been running for over a year, and stopped yesterday.  This is the code:

This is the code in the .h file:

```
@property NSString *shopOpenHour;
@property NSString *shopCloseHour;
```

This is the code in the .m file:

```
@synthesize shopOpenHour;
@synthesize shopCloseHour;
```

and:

```
if(shopOpenHour.length == 0 || shopCloseHour.length == 0)  {
```

and this also causes a crash:

```
NSLog(@"\n\nlength test: %d", (int)shopCloseHour.length);
```

This is the error I'm getting:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xb000000000003203'

It runs fine when running under a 7.1 simulator and a iPad running iOS 8.1.  I don't understand where/why NSCFNumber is "in the picture".

My question is:  any ideas of what's causing this (before I submit a RADAR?)

Comment: Sounds like this is reproducible. Why not define your own setters which check the type of their argument and dump a stack trace/breakpoint when its not `NSString`?

Comment: Maybe you defined another field called `shopCloseHour`?  Replace `shopCloseHour` with `_shopCloseHour` in your `if` and `NSLog` statements and try again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Somewhere you have assigned a NSNumber to shopCloseHour, it can happen when assigning value from json .Check

```
if ([shopCloseHour isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
    // this is a string …
}
```

Comment: Apparently it gets changed when either being stored or retrieved from NSUserDefaults.  Thank you so much... this will give me lots to do today! :D

Comment: It would be better to fix the cause of the issue. Use of the `if` statement in this answer would be helpful for debugging but the code should not remain.

Comment: To protect against this, you should use the type specific methods of NSUserDefaults to avoid this rather than using objectForKey: